# sharepoint announcement web part

Tags: web-part

I'm using SharePoint 2007,

and I'm using the announcement web part.
I have writed long description in the announcement web part.

the default possibility, sharepoint display 3 line from the announcement within the page and in order to read all the rest I need to **enter the announcement**.

1. How can I dispaly all the announcement in the site page?
2. Can control the announcement background and border color?
3. How can I let a few users add announcements and prevent all the rest for doing it?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create your own views to show the full body of the announcement.  You can even do something like this content slider I wrote on [NothingbutSharePoint](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Creating-your-own-Content-Slider-for-SharePoint.aspx).
2. To control the BG color, you'll need to find the class that is applied to the announcement background and override the style with a CEWP and style tags.
3. Give the desired users who you want to add announcements contribute permissions to the list and give everyone else read permissio.

Comment: is it possible to do this without using sharepoint designer?

Comment: Yes, the content slider is all client side script